SSIS project window turns white right at the beginning of debugging, status "Running", tricky to get the project back. How do I avoid this crash?
This takes up SSIS package with status running is not running - Stack Overflow.
SSIS project window turns white right at the beginning of debugging, status "Running":

Right click closing cannot be done:

And if I hover over the task bar icon, wait for the preview to pop up, and right click on the X of the crashed window, I can see the project again in the old window so that I can close the other window since I do not need it anymore:

And you can see that the debugging has run through, everything green:

And the whole run took just 3 seconds even though I waited minutes for the white window to go away:

And the run is flawless, no warnings or errors in the Progress /  Execution Results.
This happens at every debugging. How can I get rid of this whitened project window of Visual Studio right at the beginning of running a container?
PS: This is most likely not linked since I run into this too often, but who knows: at the same time, I also cannot change the size of any boxes in the Control Flow or Data Flow. The mouse cursor sometimes stays a double arrow after having tried resizing something, and even though it is a strange double arrow, I can double click into the boxes or click to rename things.

I saved all open projects, shut down Visual Studio, and opened the project again without running into this error again. By the same time, I could also change the size of te SSIS boxes in the Control Flow and Data Flow again.
